# How to change spacing between columns for just one page in the document

Tags: spacing, multicol

I'm using the `multicol` package for my columns. So far, I have `\setlength\columnsep{10pt}` in the preamble to set the default column separation. But for one particular page, I'd like to set the `columnsep` to 30pt.

I wasn't able to get it to work by inserting a new `\setlength` at the start of the page.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnsep{10pt} % This is the default columnsep for all pages
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\blindtext

\newpage
\setlength\columnsep{30pt} % I want the columnsep to be wider only on this page. Right now, nothing happens. The default 10pt is still being used.
\blindtext
\columnbreak
\blindtext

\newpage
\blindtext

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "I wasn't able to"? Could you please provide us with a MWE?

Comment: To add to @VahidDamanafshan ’s comment: Why weren’t you able? What happened when you did insert a `\setlength`? Nothing? Error message? Weird output? The `\columnsep` changed for the next page? For all following pages? Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/16595) that shows what you have tried so far.

Comment: If you mean that you want to change the column space but maintain total width (so change the column width) then you will have to stop the multicols environment, change parameter, and re-start. If you want to keep the column width but just separate the columns so placing them differently on the page, that would be possible.

Comment: Just provided a MWE.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To change the column width in the mid document, you should close the previous multicols, set the new `\columnsep`, and then start a new multicols environment. Try the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnsep{10pt} % This is the default columnsep for all pages
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\blindtext
\end{multicols*}
\newpage
\setlength{\columnsep}{30pt} % I want the columnsep to be wider only on this page. Right now, nothing happens. The default 10pt is still being used.
\begin{multicols}{2}
\blindtext
\end{multicols}
\newpage
\setlength\columnsep{10pt}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
%\columnbreak
\blindtext
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```