# How to produce a double column document in Latex?

Tags: two-column

I want to write double column document and I used this command `\documentclass[twoside]{article}` but it is not working, I do not know what is wrong and why it is disabled.

Comment: Replace `twoside` with `twocolumn`. `twoside` is for printing front and back of pages.

Comment: You could also, in your document, write `\twocolumn` or `\onecolumn` to switch. Or you could use `multicols`(?) -package, which balances columns very nicely.

Comment: Is it possible to have this defined in a style file?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

The `twoside` option is not about placing text in a multicolumn fashion. While `oneside` is typical for articles and reports, the `twoside` option is loaded when you want to have a double-sided document, allowing you to set the margins, asymmetrically, in order to bind the document as a book.

If you want to place text in multiple columns, you can:

- add the `twocolumn` option to your document class.
- add `\twocolumn` before the text you want to split into two columns. Later you can add `\onecolumn` to get back to the standard one column.
- load the `multicol` package, and then enclose the text you want in two (or more) columns within its environment, like `\begin{multicols}{#}...\end{multicols}`. You don't need to specify one column after this. The `#` symbolizes the number of columns the text will split into.

Note that you can combine some of these. Adding the `twocolumn` class option *and* using the `multicols` environment, will cause the text inside the latter to appear in the first half (left) of the page.

Comment: Use `\columnbreak` to mark new column start when using `multicols` solution.

Comment: +1 In my case, I chose the `multicol` environment because the `\twocolum` command created a *page break* :\. Is this always so, or can we prevent the page brake?. By the way with `\setlength{\columnsep}{<your length here>}` you control the space between columns in `multicol` see  [answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102052/how-to-change-spacing-between-columns-for-just-one-page-in-the-document).