# Text on the same row

Tags: spacing

I know a lot of these questions have been answered but I still can't get this to work. So I am trying to put Languages and Computer Skills on the same line as shown in the picture. "Languages" I managed to place on the same line to the right by adding `\hfill`. However, trying to add language skills to the right of "Basic" "Intermediate" and "Advanced" don't work. By work I mean they skip to the next line or don't align with "Basic" etc.

Here is the code:

```
\spacedlowsmallcaps{Computer Skills}\vspace{2em}\hfill\spacedlowsmallcaps{Languages}

\Description{\MarginText{Basic}\textsc{SQL}, VBA}

\Description{\MarginText{Intermediate}\LaTeX, OpenOffice, Eviews}

\Description{\MarginText{Advanced}\textsc{Microsoft Office}}
```

P.S my Latex skills are not intermediate (obviously), it came with the package I downloaded.

Thanks!

[image]

Edit: I have now managed to do this:

[image]

With the following coding:

```
\spacedlowsmallcaps{Computer     Skills}\vspace{2em}\hfill\spacedlowsmallcaps{Languages}

\Description{\MarginText{Basic}\textsc{SQL}, VBA\hfill\textsc{Swedish}\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \ \textsc{Native}}

\Description{\MarginText{Intermediate}\LaTeX, OpenOffice, Eviews\hfill\textsc{English}\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \ \textsc{Fluent}}

\Description{\MarginText{Advanced}\textsc{Microsoft Office}\hfill\textsc{Spanish}\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \ \textsc{Basic}}
```

However I would like them to be centered around the dot

Packages and document:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\reversemarginpar 
\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedleft\itshape\small#1}} 
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} 
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\cvheadingfont}{\LARGE\color{Blue}} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{colorlinks, breaklinks, urlcolor=Blue, linkcolor=Blue} 
\newcommand{\NewEntry}[3]{\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \parbox{\datebox}{\small \textit{#1}}\hspace{0em} #2 #3
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: What you want to do is make a two column environment. Unfortunately I'm on mobile so can't help much more. There a loads of good examples if you google that. Start with http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285444/112665

Comment: Thanks, will look it up! Should be noted I am currently working in overleaf instead of Texmaker because of the template I wanted to use

Comment: You possibly need a `tabular` environment, but it's very hard to say from the fragment you have posted.  Can you post a complete (but minimal) example that other people can compile?  Ideally the example should not depend on any particular environment like overleaf or TeXmaker...

Comment: Do you want the whole document or what I want to add to the Language section? I'm a bit of a newbie on the subject..

Comment: any news from you?

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned in the comments above, you are looking for a tabular like formatting with four columns.

Unfortunately, you didn't tell us, which class and packages you are using in this case.  Those `\Description`commands are not the basic LaTeX, I'd say.

Nevertheless, you should do fine, with a tabular

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}rl@{\hspace{1cm}}rl@{}}
\multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{\textsc{Computer Skills}} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\textsc{Languages}}\\
Basic & VBA, SQL & Swedish & nativ \\
Intermediate & \LaTeX{}, Openoffice, Eviva & English & fluent\\
Advanced & MS Office & Spanish & Basic
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

HTH

Jan

Comment: Thanks Jan! Helped a lot. Unfortunately I did not understand the request earlier. I will post the class and packages above

Comment: You are welcome, Niklas.  If my answer helped, please leave a +1.  

It still would be helpfull, to have a complete MWE (Minimal Working Example) in your question.